# Marker and popup on google map2

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

This is the first time I am doing something on google map2. I have stored the lat and lang to my database and I want to display all of that on my map. Now I would like to get the marker on each pin. Here is my code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function GMaps_Load()
{
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
    {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("GMaps_canvas"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        <?php if(count($val) >0){ ?>
        var cords = [23.32323,32.43455
```

22.5656,27.656464]

```
        for ( var i = 0; i < cords.length; i++ )
        {
            var marker = new GMarker( cords[ i ] );
            //alert(cords[ i ]);
            map.addOverlay( marker );
        }

        // #2a -- calculate center
        var latlngbounds = new GLatLngBounds( );
        for ( var i = 0; i < cords.length; i++ )
        {
          latlngbounds.extend( cords[ i ] );
        }
        // #2b -- set center using the calculated values
        map.setCenter( latlngbounds.getCenter( ), map.getBoundsZoomLevel( latlngbounds ) );
        //22.9946923,72.5282428

        map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(),document.createTextNode("Hello, world"));



        map.addOverlay(marker); }}
</script>
```

here  you can see in this  line of code `map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(),document.createTextNode("Hello, world"));`

I get the popup in the centre of the map but I would like it on all the pins.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you have some pressing need, you should be using Gmaps v3 now, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm reading your code wrong you're only passing 1 parameter to the marker, cords[I] would contain 1 number entry from the array instead of a valid LatLng set of values as required.

Check the API for details on how to create a LatLng.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation says that Version 2 of this API has been officially deprecated. Please use version 3.

Adding infowindows to markers is simple. See [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

With [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html) it gets more simpler :)